# Is it possible to navigate from one A-Frame scene to another without exiting VR mode on mobile?

Tags: hyperlink, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I've got an A-Frame scene from which the user can navigate to multiple different sub-scenes. Once the user entered VR mode, he can navigate to these sub scenes. I use `window.location.href` for this. Unfortunately, when entering one of the sub-scenes, VR mode has to be initiated once more. I tried to automatically enter VR mode with `enterVR();` but apparently this is by browser policy not allowed.

According to [the documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/link.html) it's supposed to be possible if the browser implements the `vrdisplayactivate` event. **BUT** it's limited to Firefox desktop, Oculus Browser, Samsung Internet, and Supermedium.

In the end my A-Frame application should be primarily used on Android. My big question is whether it is at all possible to achieve hyperlink navigation within VR on mobile, or whether I should look for an alternative approach.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't seem possible by web standards, I found a workaround for my problem with the help of jQuery.

I defined an `a-entity` with nothing but an ID inside my main scene

```
<a-entity id="includedScene"></a-entity>
```

And instead of using `window.location.href = 'xxx.html'` I used jQuerys load function to replace the `includedScene` entity with whatever sub scene I want to load:

```
$("#includedScene").load('xxx.html');
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in the index.html

```
<script src="path/to/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

No. Fullscreen mode doesn't persist on page navigation. It's a constraint of the Web standard